# Assign rank to cell values based on defined number of ranks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a series of values that I need to rank by a previously set number of ranks. In this particular case, I need to rank the values in 8 different grades/ranks/categories. There are 56 values, so every rank would have 7 values (56/8=7). I need to assign with formula number 1 to the lowest 7 values, number 2 to the next 7 values and so on.

|value|______|rank|

103,86_______1-8

102,17________?

98,34_________?

88,89_________?

...

Using Excel 2019.

Thanks!

Comment: What if, for example, 10 entries are equal to the lowest value? How do you decide which 8 of those 10 are given a rank of 1, and which 2 have to be assigned a rank of 2?

Comment: Let's presume that that would not happen. But what could happen and is a problem is that two of the lowest values could be 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=ROUNDUP((RANK(A1,A$1:A$56,1)+COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)-1)/7,0)
```

**Note:** This accounts for possible duplicates in A:A.

Comment: Thank you for the response. 
This formula returns rank 1 for 8 times, and rank 8 for 6 times. All other vales are ranked 7 times, as it should be. 
I have additional question: what if I wanted to reverse order? To assign to he lowest 7 ranks number 8 instead of 1?

Comment: It worked out for me with 7 values for each rank. You have exactly 56 values? Formula set up correctly in each cell? To reverse, use `RANK(A1,A$1:A$56,0)`

Comment: Yes, the formula is set correctly. When using reversed order, the highest values return 0.

Comment: Mind sharing some actual sample data of 56 values? @IgorK

Comment: Don't know if there is a better way, sorry for c/p like this. 72,87
77,74
68,14
84,57
68,74
71,78
68,77
64,69
65,77
66,71
66,46
66,91
66,33
66,84
56,99
64,28
59,79
57,34
60,52
55,64
58,02
52,02
53,23
54,46
54,85
52,18
52,61
53,39
51,00
51,91
50,86
49,98
49,88
47,37
47,38
47,11
43,28
44,11
46,45
43,54
44,56
43,12
38,49
40,38
34,15
38,72
43,08
38,47
34,20
30,20
30,77
33,48
32,79
27,51
0,00
0,00